# Wrong locale for dates in Laravel app in production on Heroku

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade, php-carbon

I have an issue with dates locale in my Laravel App hosted on Heroku.

In the blade files I show the dates value like this:

```
{{ $user->dateBirth? Carbon\Carbon::parse($user->dateBirth)->formatLocalized('%d/%b/%Y') : ''}}
```

I have set the locale in AppServiceProvider:

```
public function boot(Charts $charts){
     Carbon::setLocale('it');
     setlocale(LC_TIME, 'it_IT', 'it', 'IT', 'Italian', 'it_IT.UTF-8');
}
```

I want to show the month in IT locale, like **23/Gen/2021**, on my localhost this works fine, but in production on Heroku the value showed is **23/Jan/2021**.

How can i solve it?

Comment: Have you tried to clear the cache in the production environment?

Comment: yes, i have done this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It simply means Heroku does not have `it` locale installed on the OS so `LC_TIME` won't work and `formatLocalized` neither. Hopefully, Carbon has its own translations with even more formats supported than `formatLocalized` (which actually rely on OS locales installed). See `->isoFormat()` in https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/#api-localization

```
{{ $user->dateBirth ? Carbon\Carbon::parse($user->dateBirth)->isoFormat('DD/MMM/YYYY') : ''}}
```

My recommandation is to always use `->isoFormat()` so your code works on any machine with no extra install/setting, and those can be customized so you can change the Carbon translations without impacting the rest.

Comment: Note that P. K. Tharindu is still correct about using `'locale' => 'it'` in Laravel instead of doing `Carbon::setLocale('it')` manually if your site is only available in Italian, else you can call `Carbon\Carbon::parse($user->dateBirth)->locale('it')` to change the object with user locale. For timezone, it should rather not be hard-coded and use the browser one.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of doing that, try changing the below variables in your `config/app.php`:

```
'timezone' => 'Europe/Rome',
'locale' => 'it',
```